# Selectively displaying data from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table named `profile` in a MySQL database which contains data in a column called `name`.  Currently my PHP echoes out all the data in `name`.  How would I amend/change the code such that I display:

1. only the most recent 5 entries in the 'name' column?
2. specifically the nth dataset in the 'name' column?

This is my code:

```
<?php
// connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $databaseName);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

// store data in $names
$names = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM profile");

// print out data 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($names)) {
    echo $row['name'] . "</br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: "Recent" according to what? What are the other columns of that table?

Read tutorials about ORDER BY and LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the ORDER BY clause along with a LIMIT...this is assuming that you have something to order by which will give you newest to oldest such as a timestamp

```
$names = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM profile ORDER BY tstamp desc limit 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming xxx is a column representing your "name" data entry order, use

```
$query = SELECT name FROM profile ORDER BY xxx DESC limit 5
```

2nd part:

```
$query = SELECT name FROM profile ORDER BY xxx DESC limit n, 1
```